# Temporizador (CountDownTimer) en distintas actividades

Tags: java, android-studio

Muy buenas.

Estoy creando una aplicación para un escape room y necesito que el temporizador de 1h aparezca en las distintas actividades de mi app.

Lo he creado en la primera página con el siguiente código:

```
CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
long mInitialTime =
        0L +
                DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 59 +
                DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 59;
public TextView mTextView;

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mInitialTime, 1000) {
        StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
            mTextView.setText("Tiempo agotado");
            Intent i = new Intent(contexto.getApplicationContext(), videoant.class);
            contexto.startActivity(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setLength(0);
            time.append(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000d)));
            mTextView.setText(time.toString());
        }
    }.start();
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Muchísimas gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: Has pensado crear un fragmento reutilizable ?

Comment: Soy bastante nuevo en Android Studio. ¿Podrías especificar un poco más? :)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias generar una clase que extienda de android.os.CountDownTimer, pasando el contexto y el TextView que queres actualizar.

```
 //Ejemplo clase MyCountDownTimer que extiende CountDownTimer
    public class MyCountDownTimer extends android.os.CountDownTimer {
        private android.widget.TextView mTextView;
        private android.content.Context context;
        private StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();
        private static long mInitialTime =
                0L +
                        DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 59 +
                        DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS * 59;
    
        public MyCountDownTimer(Context context, TextView mTextView) {
            super(MyCountDownTimer.mInitialTime, 1000);
            this.context = context;
            this.mTextView = mTextView;
        }
    
        public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, Context context, TextView mTextView) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            this.context = context;
            this.mTextView = mTextView;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setLength(0);
            time.append(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(Math.round(millisUntilFinished / 1000d)));
            mTextView.setText(time.toString());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
    
            mTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
            mTextView.setText("Tiempo agotado");
            Intent i = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), videoant.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
    
    
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo de uso:

Y desde los activity ejemplo:

```
Context ctx = (Context)this;
//TextView mTextView -> aqui asignas el view que debe actualizarse.
MyCountDownTimer contador = new MyCountDownTimer(ctx, mTextView);
contador.start();
```